# How to determine that a certain eigenvalue is doubly degenerate?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Given a symmetric matrix $X$. I ask myself, how to determine that a certain eigenvalue $\lambda$ is (exactly) doubly degenerate?

I thought about several approaches:

1. Calculate the derivative of $ \det\left(X-x{\bf 1}\right)$ and evaluate it at $\lambda$. This should vanish in case of degeneracy:
   $$\frac{d}{dx} \det\left(X-x{\bf 1}\right)\Biggr|_{x=\lambda}\overset!=0$$
2. Try to find the two dimensional eigenspace connected to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Since I want to code this, I'm looking for the most efficient way. Option 2. seems to be a little to much, compared to what I need, but is there a more efficient way than just expand the characteristic polynomial, differentiate and evaluate it? Can't we make use of the fact that $ \det\left(X-\lambda{\bf 1}\right)=0$?

Thanks to Kaster I also found this at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative):

> In particular, if $A$ is invertible, we have
> $    \frac{\mathrm{d} \det(A)}{\mathrm{d} \alpha} = \det(A) \operatorname{tr}\left(A^{-1} \frac{\mathrm{d} A}{\mathrm{d} \alpha}\right). $

But this doesn't seem to apply (when I substitute $A=X-x{\bf 1}; \alpha=x$), since  $A$ would not be invertible by definition, so I end up applying [Jacobi's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Applications):

> $$\frac{d}{dx} \det\left(X-x{\bf 1}\right)= tr \left( adj(X-x{\bf 1}) \right)$$

Comment: What does "doubly degenerated" (this sounds like a dangerous guy!) mean in this context? That the eigenvalue is a double root of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @Kaster that's what [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant_in_relation_to_other_notions) told me. Why should it be wrong?

Comment: For an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity exactly 2, you also need that the second derivative of the characteristic polynomial does NOT vanish at $\lambda$.

Comment: @user2566092 true,thanks for pointing this out; in fact the matrices I have in mind would not allow larger multiplicities than 2...

Comment: Are you going to use floating point arithmetic, or exact rational number or finite field arithmetic?

Comment: Rather than evaluating the Wikipedia formula at $a=x$, can you evaluate the limiting value as $a\to x?$  Another idea: if this is a numerical computation, it shouldn't be that hard to compute the rank of $X-x\mathbf{1}.$

Comment: @WillOrrick +1; good question ("no idea, can I?") and nice (other) idea...

Comment: Since you seem to already know what the eigenvalue is, without already having computed the characteristic polynomial, do you also already know one eigenvector for the eigenvalue?

Comment: "no idea, canI?" : Yes, you can.  Let $A=X-a\mathbf{1}.$  Both $\det A$ and its derivative are polynomials in $a.$  Since the right side of the Wikipedia formula equals a polynomial expression for $a$ close to, but not equal to, $x,$ you should be able to evaluate this limit.

Comment: @user2566092 I thought about floating point, since it seems easiest to me. Other approaches are also welcome. Indeed I also know at least one eigenvector! So...(and I think I can see it coming)

Comment: @WillOrrick but I will need to expand the polynomials in this case, something I would like to avoid...

Comment: @draks these kinds of matrix computations can be tricky with floating point, e.g. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Computation . They recommend using special kinds of decompositions like SVD to compute matrix rank instead of just standard Gaussian elimination, and also point out that even then, you have to threshold the singular values to determine if they're supposed to be zero or not.

Comment: @user2566092 this doesn't sound promising. What would you do?

Comment: Honestly, I'd use LAPACK library instead of coding linear algebra from scratch, LAPACK is free and has no sticky licensing issues and it can do just about any linear algebra computation (and robustly) and it's heavily optimized to be as fast as possible with floating point.